# Error AspectJ eclipse. Java head space

Tags: spring, maven, ide, build

Estoy intentando hacer build de un proyecto que usa AspectJ. Cuando lleva un 41% del proceso, cancela dando el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segun he podido ver, este error suele estar referido a ejecuciones java, y desde RUN/RUN CONFIGURATIONS es editable. Sin embargo, en mi caso no es una ejecución, es un Build, aunque me da la sensación de que AspectJ es una ejecución java como tal. ¿Alguna idea de como podría aumentarse el Head Space de AspectJ? Sospecho que tendría que cambiar algo en alguno de los archivos del repositorio de maven del plugin, pero lo desconozco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes ampliar la memoria que puede usar Maven durante la compilación. Al fin y al cabo, Maven y AspectJ son herramientas hechas en Java. De [la documentación](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html):

> ### .mvn/jvm.config file:
>
> Starting with Maven 3.3.1+ you can define JVM configuration via ${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/jvm.config file which
>   means you can define the options for your build on a per project base.
>   This file will become part of your project and will be checked in
>   along with your project. So no need anymore for MAVEN_OPTS, .mavenrc
>   files. So for example if you put the following JVM options into the
>   ${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/jvm.config file
>
> ```
> -Xmx2048m -Xms1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true
> ```

Crea un fichero jvm.config dentro de una carpeta .mvn en la raíz de tu proyecto con las opciones de la máquina virtual que necesites, posiblemente con poner

```
 -Xmx2048m
```

sea suficiente.

Otra forma más general es tener una variable de entorno en el sistema `MAVEN_OPTS`, con los parámetros que pasarías al comando `java`, algo como

```
 set MAVEN_OPTS =-Xms256m -Xmx2048m
```

Comment: Crear la carpeta .mvn en la raiz del proyecto a funcionado perfectamente. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Puedes *aceptar* la respuesta para marcar la pregunta como respondida ;)